# Intercept FIleSytemCall for Deletion

Tags: .net, windows, visual-c++, operating-system

Is there a way to detect deletion of a file before windows performs the deletion? I found FileSystemWatcher class but the event is raised only after the delete action is performed but I want to trap the delete action once the user/process chooses to delete it. You can monitor the file system table but looking for a better approach. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did it by hoooking NtSetFileInformation API using mhook library, Worked like a charm. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simpliest way is to use a hook to get notified (and eventually to stop) the process. It can't be done in .NET so you have to `DllImport` a lot of structures and few functions to P/Invoke.

Let's start your job with the `NtSetFileInformation` (undocumented) function. It's the function called by anything else when a file need to be deleted (with the `FileDispositionInformation` structure).

Now the problem is how to hook that function (good luck, it's not easy). A good choice can be to use [Microsoft Detours](http://www.microsoft.com/about/legal/en/us/intellectualproperty/iplicensing/programs/detours.aspx). Take a look to [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30140/API-Hooking-with-MS-Detours) for an example. Its problem is that it's not free. An alternative solution (with a reasonable price and with a .NET interface) is [Deviare](http://www.nektra.com/products/deviare-api-hook-windows/download) but I never tried even their free version so I don't know how much it's good. If someone else knows a good interception tool...

Comment: Thanks, I actually dont want to stop the process from deleting the file. I want to make a secure copy of the file and let deletion happen.

Comment: @Gopikanna it's the same (hard) way. The big problem is to **detect** when someone/something is trying to delete a file (different functions use different methods, NtSetFileInformation is just the deepest one). When you're there what to do is (kind) trivial.

Comment: Thanks, I will try API hooking and hope I can make it :)

Comment: @Gopikanna a small tip for a complex task: start with the linked article on CodeProject, it's good (if you'll use detour).

Comment: I have a doubt, If I successfully write an API hook for NtSetFileInformation using Detours, does that mean any number of processes that may call this api will go through the detour function I wrote. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Everyone that will call NtSetFileInformation will first pass by your function, no matters which method they're using to delete a file (shell, _basic_ Windows API, NtSetFileInformation directly or whatever else).

Comment: Thanks.. I am trying to find NtSetFileINformation but its nowhere. Do you have any idea where to find it.

Comment: Oh.. It is this one I guess http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557671(v=vs.85).aspx..

Answer (score 1):

You need a filesystem filter driver. However I strongly suggest that if you don't know the answer you probably shouldn't be doing it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg462968.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but not looking for driver level solutions. Writting a driver is not feasible one for me :). I was looking for api level solution.

Comment: I may be completely wrong, Is it possible to run a service that holds a lock on the file so that whenever something tries to delete it, My service can find it out.

Comment: If you want to PREVENT deletion, just hold an open handle (open with access FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES) but without FILE_SHARE_DELETE. Finding out that someone attempted to delete it is harder.

Comment: Oh... but I want to let the deletion happen eventually after I make a copy of the file.Thanks.

Comment: This sort of low-level file trickery really belongs in a filter driver, not an application. (For example, you can hang the other application by doing a `Sleep(INFINITE)` in your "last-second copy" code. Which becomes a security issue if the other application is running under a different security context.) Maybe you can just dig an old copy of the file out of the volume snapshot database.

Comment: @Gopikanna, have you looked at shadow copy services (VSS)? Edit: As Raymond Chen suggests...

Comment: @Ben Raymond I am not sure whether I can use it but will look into it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Or may try **ICopyHook** interface.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776049%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

In **CopyCallback** method use **FO_DELETE** in wFunc parameter, to specify delete operation.

*Disadvantage:*
Only prevent deletion in Windows Shell.