# File operation in C# using SHFileOperation

Tags: c#, file

I am new to .net programming in C#; Currently I'm developing a project in which I want a functionality that happens when a file is deleted.

I can move this file to my custom folder named "recovery", but I don't know how to do this, please help me.

I want to use `SHFileOperation` to do this.

Comment: Why not using [System.IO.File.Move(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move.aspx), but SHFileOperation?

Comment: Actually, rather use [System.IO.Directory.Move(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.move.aspx), as this can move both files and directories.

Comment: If you want to automatically copy a file before it is deleted by some other process (as suggested by the answers given here already), then though luck: You are in for some advanced programming tasks. Just for getting you in the right mood, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10727844/intercept-filesytemcall-for-deletion or here: http://forum.sysinternals.com/deletefile-hook_topic23634.html

Comment: Directory.Mode() cannot move to a different volume, e.g. from C:\ to D:\

Comment: Why delete the file, instead just move it to the recovery folder for delete operation.

Answer (score -1):

You may use FileSystemWatcher, listen to OnDelete event, then copy to custom folder.
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. OnDelete is fired after the file is deleted.