# Regarding file permission in C#

Tags: c#, windows, file-permissions, keyboard-hook, rights-management

I have an issue regarding file permission. I am continuously watching on one folder {Workspace} using FileSystemWatcher. When I am trying to delete file from workspace, Watcher will give me deleted event after file is deleted.

I want to hook file delete event of windows. when user try to delete file from workspace then my custom message pop-up and ask user for confirmation "Are you sure you want to delete the file ??" if user press 'YES' then n then file is deleted otherwise do nothing.

So, please help me to introduce my custom message when user try to delete file from my workspace.

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot do it in C#. This is quite a very advanced topic, and you need C or C++ for it. You need something called File System Filter. You may look at this https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43586/File-System-Filter-Driver-Tutorial#_Toc244423398

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intercept FIleSytemCall for Deletion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10727844/intercept-filesytemcall-for-deletion)

Comment: hey Kim Hoang ,
I visit your link but i can't understand. can you please help me to implement File System Filter Driver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not possible by using filesystemwatcher. with a filesystemwatcher, you can watch and receive events, but it is not a hook to manipulate the functionality of windows.

Comment: forgive filesystemwatcher. 
Is there any other way to implement my requirement ??